# Are multiple anti-virus programs prone to conflicts on Windows?

Tags: windows, anti-virus

I have not used Windows in years, so am rather out of date, but recently I was kibitzing with a friend about their laptop, that runs Windows 10.

I noticed that it had McAfee anti-virus installed as well as Windows Security; I always had the impression that multiple anti-virus programs were not a good idea, and I did find this question, from several years ago, that seemed to confirm that idea:

[Multiple Antivirus Software](https://superuser.com/questions/257120/multiple-antivirus-software)

but wondered if this is still the current opinion.
Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In Windows 10 and later, Windows Security will detect the presence of a
third-party antivirus product, such as McAfee, and will disable
real-time protection, leaving it to McAfee.

Thus, no conflict is possible.

Comment: +1 Any **one** third party antivirus has always been fine, as Windows' own security will step aside & let the 3rd party take over. The problem was always if you install **two** or more real-time anti-virus suites. They can fight & results are unpredictable… to bad. tbh, in this case I'd dump the McAfee though… it's never been very good.

Comment: This is why I really like Emsisoft. It runs two real-time scanning engines side-by-side and it's designed to do exactly that. It uses their own scanning engine and BitDefender's excellent scanning engine as well.

Comment: @Nilpo - my gateway has similar, dual Sophos/Avira [plus whatever each individual computer has.] Though, for clarification in case this appears to conflict with my first comment - of course, they are *designed* to run in tandem, unlike two random AVs on one personal computer.

Comment: I am not sure if this answers the question.  The OP is asking about multiple virus scanners running, not just one.